# What do the Contour Levels Produced by Matlab Function Contourc Represent

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have been trying to understand what the contour levels are.

As far as I understand a contour of the function $Z(x,y)$ is a set of points in the $(x,y)$ plane, such that $Z(x,y)$ is fixed at some constant value, that constant value is the contour **level**. 
 
Matlab docs state that the contourc function takes an argument that determines the levels upon which the contours are computed. 
 
 
I wanted to try that out, so I constructed a picture with $10$ rectangles, each of which has a distinct depth starting from $0.1$ ending up at $1.0$, and I ran the contour function to see the highlighted contours according to the specified levels in the input, but the results weren't expected.

For instance, I ran the code on $0.1$ contour level and the contour function produces all the contours in the picture, not only the ones with $0.1$ level.

[image: The picture shows the aforementioned scenario]

Here is the Matlab code used to construct the picture and find its contours:

```
pic = zeros(500, 500);
val = 0.1;
shift = 40;

for j = 1:10
  for i= 50:450
    pic(shift*j,i) = val;
  end
  for i= 50:450
    pic(shift*j+25,i) = val;
  end
  for i = shift*j: shift*j+25
    pic(i, 50) = val;
    pic(i,450) = val;
  end
  val = val + 0.1;

end

imshow(pic);
figure(2);
contour(pic, [0.1 0.1]);
```

I'd be so grateful if someone could clue me in.

Comment: Try `contour` without the second argument

Answer (score 1):

So you:

> I constructed a picture with 10 rectangles, each of which has a distinct depth starting from 0.1 ending up at 1.0

and then:

> I ran the code on 0.1 contour level

The matlab function is doing the right thing. A rectangle of height 0.1 has a contour at 0.1.  A rectangle of height 1 also has a contour at 0.1 (and 0.05 and 0.5, and 0.9999999, but not at 1.000001).  The rectangle exists from 0 to 1 (in this case).